# How to Get Previous Value in Formula/SQL Statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 columns, This Month, Last Month, Remarks

I want to get the value of the 'previous month' where the value is R-Factor value from previous month of the same Carrier ID.

I have the statement for This Month this works well, but I could not pull out the Last Month.

This Month Formula Statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (R_Factor) 
FROM Table_Carrier_Profile 
WHERE Carrier_Profile_ID= target.[@field:Carrier_Profile_ID] 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

[image: Records]

[image: Expected Result Table]

This Month Formula Statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (R_Factor) 
FROM Table_Carrier_Profile 
WHERE Carrier_Profile_ID= target.[@field:Carrier_Profile_ID] 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

[Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmbZw.png)
[Expected Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv2Zs.png)

Records

| Column A | Column B | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZZKPNQW0 | 8Y9NT78U | 12/01/2023 | 0.367 |
| 5R46UC9I | 8Y9NT78U | 11/01/2023 | 0.252 |
| 97CSSNY8 | 8Y9NT78U | 10/01/2023 | 0.239 |
| ZRQL6ZD6 | 8Y9NT78U | 09/01/2023 | 0.308 |

Expected Result Table with regards to R-Factor Value

| This Month | Last Month |
| --- | --- |
| 0.367 | 0.252 |

Comment: That doesn't look like MySQL code.  Are you sure you've got the right tags on your question?

Comment: The `TOP` keyword is only supported by SQL Server and Sybase, and not MySQL. What is your actual environment? Also, we **NEVER** want screenshots of sample data or results.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear yet. The example SQL in the question filters based on the `Carrier_Profile_ID` column, but seems to show results based on the `Carrier_ID` column.

The confusion makes me less confident in this answer, but one possible option uses the `LAG()` windowing function:

```
SELECT [This Month], [Last Month]
FROM (
    SELECT Carrier_Profile_ID, R_Factor As [This Month]
        , LAG(R_Factor) OVER (PARTITION BY Carrier_ID ORDER BY [Date]) [Last Month]
    FROM Table_Carrier_Profile 
) t
WHERE t.Carrier_Profile_ID = target.[@field:Carrier_Profile_ID]
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/OHMkVEwa